# SELECT on same table for Multiple key value pairs

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
id keyword_id value   category_id asset_id
 1          2 abc.jpg        4424      479
 2          3 Jpeg           4424      479
 3          4 400*600        4424      479
 4          2 def.jpg        4424      603
 5          3 Jpeg           4424      603
 6          4 500*700        4424      603
```

I want to fetch values depending on multiple pairs like (`keyword id = 3 and value like '%Jpeg%'`) And (`keyword id = 2 and value like '%abc%'`).

This should return only one value with `asset_id 479` because it meets both the criteria.

I am running a query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT asset_id FROM asset_keyword_table where category_id = 4424
AND (( keyword_id = 2 AND value LIKE '%abc%') AND ( keyword_id = 3 AND 
value LIKE '%Jpeg%'));
```

But EXPLAIN this query returns Impossible WHERE clause.
What is the way to get this working.
This query is generated by BE code so blocks likes this can be many -

```
( keyword_id = 2 AND value LIKE '%abc%')
```

depending on user input. And the blocks separated by AND or OR is also determined by User. Using aliases is not possible because there is no limit on the number of blocks.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have to use `OR` instead of `AND`: `(( keyword_id = 2 AND value LIKE '%abc%') OR ( keyword_id = 3 AND value LIKE '%Jpeg%'));`

Comment: OR or AND is determined from input. Or will return 2 results with asset_id = 479 and asset_id = 603, I want only asset_id that match both the condition

Comment: You can try nested queries: `SELECT DISTINCT Asset_ID FROM asset_keyword_table WHERE ( category_id = 4424 AND keyword_id = 2 AND value LIKE '%abc%' ) AND ( Asset_ID in ( SELECT DISTINCT Asset_ID FROM asset_keyword_table WHERE category_id = 4424 AND keyword_id = 3 AND value LIKE '%Jpeg%' ))   ... OR Asset_ID in ...`

Comment: This seems to be working..

Comment: Okay great, I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested queries should give you the desired result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT asset_id FROM asset_keyword_table WHERE 
( category_id = 4424 AND keyword_id = 2 AND value LIKE '%abc%' )
AND asset_id IN
( SELECT DISTINCT asset_id FROM asset_keyword_table WHERE 
   category_id = 4424 AND keyword_id = 3 AND value LIKE '%Jpeg%' )
/*  OR asset_id IN
( SELECT DISTINCT asset_id FROM asset_keyword_table WHERE
   category_id = 4424 AND keyword_id = 4 AND value LIKE '%500%' ) */
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cbac4/6)

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter the total number of rows that match with your condition.

```
SELECT  Asset_ID
FROM    asset_keyword_table 
WHERE   category_id = 4424
        AND 
        (( keyword_id = 2 AND value LIKE '%abc%') 
        OR (keyword_id = 3 AND value LIKE '%Jpeg%'))
GROUP   BY Asset_ID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2 -- number of rows that matched the condition
```

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efa558/1).

Comment: What if i receive a request for the following from the input


    `SELECT DISTINCT asset_id FROM asset_keyword_table where category_id = 4424
AND (( keyword_id = 2 AND value LIKE '%abc%') AND ( keyword_id = 3 AND 
value LIKE '%Jpeg%') OR (keyword_id = 4 AND 
value LIKE '%200%'));`
Since code is BE generated

Comment: it won't work. all rows will be return as long as it will much to **any** of your condition above and not all.